# Ошибка компиляции в qt

Tags: qt

Установил visual studio 2015 после установил  qt5.9, но не легла на студию (не легла из за того что там раньше установил по ошибке qt).

Не получается теперь пути прописать и как примера не где нету принт скирина. куда и какие файлы прописать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На снимках у вас Qt Creator и причем тут Visual Studio? Вы хотите из креатора студийный компилятор использовать?

Comment: бросьте  пожалуйста свои пути что бы можно было посмотреть и просто вставить

Comment: если студия установлена, то нужно зайти на вкладку компиляторы и подключить студийный компилятор. Обычно он сам подцепляется, но видимо что то не так установили.  Потом на вкладке профили qt подцепите компилятор к версии библиотеки.

Comment: @Cerbo да студия у меня стоит

Comment: @KoVadim в том то и суть  вадим я не знаю стандартный путь и прошу у вас как он выглядит как называется исполняемый фаил ибо уже забыл  (экзешник и стандартный путь ( просто у меня по стандартному устанвка была ) )

Comment: что то ыот такое `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86`. (FYI: имена людей пишутся с большой буквы)